# Android 4.0.3 keyboard exceeds bottom display border

Tags: android, view, keyboard

In my own AOSP build on target and emulator I have the issue that the Android keyboard exceeds the display boarder on the bottom side. The 4th row with the space bar is only displayed half and cut by the bottom boarder of the screen.

The same issue can be seen on the standard google emulator. Just press on the search bar to reproduce it.

I'm using a 320x480 mdpi display layout, for the emulator e.g. the predefined defintion for the "3.2" HVGA slider (ADP1)"

It seems to be an issue for Android 4.0.3 as with Android 4.2.2 I cannot reproduce it.

Is this known and is there a solution avialable?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile found a solution by myself. Probably it is useful for someone else:

see packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/res/values/dimens.xls

Android 4.0.3/4 uses a 240dip height for the key_preview_backing_height (6 preview rows maximum with 40dip each). Together with the more_suggestions_row_height of 40dip already 280dips of the display are used.

Together with the status bar (~25dip) a 3,2" display with 320x480 pix does not offer enought height to display the entire keyboard.

Reducing the number of preview rows to 5 solves the issue for me. This reduces key_preview_backing_height to 200dip and gives enough space for the keybaord.

BR,
klo ZwoFünf